# how to insert a structured identifiable array in a list?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

```
struct Gg: Identifiable{
    
    let id: Int
    let task: String
}

struct ContentView: View {

@State private var items = [Gg(id: 1, task:"take the trash out"), Gg(id: 2, task:"Go for a run")]


var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
           
            ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                VStack {
                    List(self.items, id: \.self) { index in
                        Text("\(index)")
                    }

}}
```

I get the following error

Cannot declare entity named '$id'; the '$' prefix is reserved for implicitly-synthesized declarations
Initializer 'init(_:id:rowContent:)' requires that 'Gg' conform to 'Hashable'

quit new and starting out appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You iterate by item, not by indices, so it is simply

```
            VStack {
                List(self.items) { item in
                    Text(item.task)
                }
```

Comment: what about if I want to add it from another UI view such as the following: AddTaskUIView(title: "Add Item", isShown: $isPresented, text: $text, onDone: { text in
                    
                    self.items.append(text)
               
                    })